# How to get world-space matrix of any pose bone?

Tags: python, scripting

Is there a command for getting world-space matrix of pose bones, same as `obj.matrix_world` for objects? I found `pose_bone.matrix`, but it gives weird result for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes:

As the documentation says, a pose bones matrix is in object space, this means - unless the object has no loc/scale/rot applied, you will have to apply the objects matrix.

> matrix_final = [`obj.matrix_world`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.Object.matrix_world) `@` [`pose_bone.matrix`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PoseBone.html#bpy.types.PoseBone.PoseBone.matrix)

This test script adds an empty at the pose-bone.

```
# Assume we are in pose mode with an active bone

import bpy
from bpy import context

pose_bone = context.active_pose_bone

# we can get the object from the pose bone
obj = pose_bone.id_data
matrix_final = obj.matrix_world @ pose_bone.matrix


# now we can view the matrix by applying it to an object
obj_empty = bpy.data.objects.new("Test", None)
context.collection.objects.link(obj_empty)
obj_empty.matrix_world = matrix_final
```

Answer (score 5):

[`mathutils`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#module-mathutils) now uses the PEP 465 binary operator for multiplying matrices.

```
matrix_final = obj.matrix_world * pose_bone.matrix
```

becomes

```
matrix_final = obj.matrix_world @ pose_bone.matrix
```

---

Since 2.8 object are now stored in [Collections](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendData.html?highlight=collections#bpy.types.BlendData.collections), so :

```
context.scene.objects.link(obj_empty)
```

becomes

```
bpy.data.collections['Collection'].objects.link(obj_empty)
```

Here is the complete script updated:

```
# Assume we are in pose mode with an active bone,
# and a collection named collecion exist

import bpy
from bpy import context

pose_bone = context.active_pose_bone

# we can get the object from the pose bone
obj = pose_bone.id_data
matrix_final = obj.matrix_world @ pose_bone.matrix


# now we can view the matrix by applying it to an object
obj_empty = bpy.data.objects.new("Test", None)
bpy.data.collections['Collection'].objects.link(obj_empty)
obj_empty.matrix_world = matrix_final
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful !
But now I would like to ask, I have global_matrix, how to convert it to localtransform (localtion / rotation / scale)?

Answer (score 4):

**Again with tip to tail offset.**

Slight addition to [@ideasman42](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1287/15543)'s answer to enable globally locating to tip or tail of bone based on an offset. 0 is as above at fat end of bone (head), 1 at skinny end (tail).

This is to emulate somewhat the option in copy transform constraints to locate with offset along bone.

The vector

```
(pb.head - pb.tail)
```

describes the object space vector from head to tail
A translation matrix is created to translate point of interest  locally along the bone.

```
# Assume we are in pose mode with an active bone

import bpy
from bpy import context
from mathutils import Matrix

# add empty half way along bone
offset = 0.5 # 0 for tail 1 for tip.

pb = context.active_pose_bone

T =  Matrix.Translation(
    offset * (pb.tail - pb.head)
    )

# we can get the object from the pose bone
obj = pb.id_data
matrix_final = obj.matrix_world @ (T @ pb.matrix)


# now we can view the matrix by applying it to an object
obj_empty = bpy.data.objects.new("Test", None)
context.collection.objects.link(obj_empty)
obj_empty.matrix_world = matrix_final
```