# How to get a pose bones rotation (custom exporter)

Tags: python

Well after weeks of searching online and nothing found I decided to ask online. I want to get the x, y and z rotation of a pose bone or even just a bone. I can't seem to get it working I have a rough understanding of matrices and would really like it if I could figure this out. So please guys help me get the x y and z rotation of a pose bone/bone (I am writing a custom armature exporter)

Comment: Welcome Jp Silver :) These answers might help: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3618/global-pose-rotation-of-a-bone/5438#5438, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/how-to-get-world-space-matrix-of-any-pose-bone Please start with the tour: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Anyway, enjoy blender.SE!