# Set the world_matrix of a bone

Tags: animation, armature, matrix

I need to copy the world matrix of a bone and assign it to another bone. Both have different parents. Pretty much what the copy transforms constraint does, but for a single frame without dependencies, because I need it to be set in a certain frame and then put a loc/rot keyframe there. 
I am fine with either a script or manual solution (like cursor to selected -> selection to cursor, but for rotations as well)

I found this: [Global Pose/Rotation of a bone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3618/global-pose-rotation-of-a-bone)
But that script gives me an error, that the expected matrix would need to be 3x3, if I put mat.to_3x3() behind it, nothing happens at all. Also since both bones in that script share a branch in the hierarchy I'm not sure if it would suit me in the first place.
I don't care about scale at all.
Thanks

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109815/how-can-i-move-a-posebone-to-a-specific-world-space-position)

Comment: perfect, exactly what I need, I don't know why I didn't find that myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link batFINGER provider is the correct answer, just in case someone is wondering: The reason why my bone was expecting a matrix 3x3 is that I used

```
bone = C.active_bone
```

the correct way to get the bone is

```
bone = my_armature.pose.bones['my_bone']
```

Comment: Perhaps `C.active_pose_bone` whist in pose mode, may have been Ok.