# How to get posebone global location

Tags: python, add-on, motion-capture

I use the below code to retrieve location of pose.bone, but it always give 0 (or -0).
It seems the `pose.bone` location is the relative position of its parent so it will not-zero value once I grab pose.bone to somewhere?! 
Is there a way to get "global location(X, Y, Z)" of `pose.bone`??

```
for action in bpy.data.actions:
    print(action)
    for fcurve in action.fcurves:
         print("data_path:" + fcurve.data_path + ", channel " + str(fcurve.array_index))
         for keyframe in fcurve.keyframe_points:
              print(keyframe.co)
```

```
data_path:pose.bones["Bone.011"].location, channel 0 
Vector (13.0000, -0.0000) 
Vector (29.0000, -0.0000) 
Vector (40.0000, -0.0000) 
Vector (45.0000, -0.0000) 
Vector (83.0000, -0.0000) 
Vector (110.0000, -0.0000) 
data_path:pose.bones["Bone.011"].location, channel 1 
Vector (13.0000, 0.0000) 
Vector (29.0000, 0.0000) 
Vector (40.0000, 0.0000) 
Vector (45.0000, 0.0000) 
Vector (83.0000, 0.0000) 
Vector (110.0000, 0.0000) 
data_path:pose.bones["Bone.011"].location, channel 2 
Vector (13.0000, -0.0000) 
Vector (29.0000, -0.0000) 
Vector (40.0000, -0.0000) 
Vector (45.0000, -0.0000) 
Vector (83.0000, -0.0000) 
Vector (110.0000, -0.0000) 
data_path:location, channel 0 
Vector (13.0000, 0.0245) 
Vector (45.0000, -3.3037) 
Vector (83.0000, 0.0245) 
Vector (110.0000, 1.5101) 
data_path:location, channel 1 
Vector (13.0000, -0.0075) 
Vector (45.0000, -0.0075) 
Vector (83.0000, -0.0075) 
Vector (110.0000, -0.0075) 
data_path:location, channel 2 
Vector (13.0000, 3.0031) 
Vector (45.0000, 2.5048) 
Vector (83.0000, 1.8442) 
Vector (110.0000, 1.8442)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit of a [duplicate of this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/how-to-get-world-space-matrix-of-any-pose-bone), but just to complete the picture, to get the global location of your pose bone, you need to multiply the bone's location by the armature and the bone's transform matrices (sounds complicated, but is actually simple):

```
p = bpy.context.active_pose_bone  # Our pose bone
o = bpy.context.object            # Our armature object
global_location = o.matrix_world * p.matrix * p.location
```

Comment: but how if the p.location is 0? then the global_location is always 0?

Comment: Not an expert in linear algebra, but from what I understand, not necessarily: http://mathinsight.org/matrix_vector_multiplication

Comment: not sure about what "not necessarily" mean.. do you mean value of p.location is 0 will not result in global_location to 0?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the transform matrices of the armature and the p's parent bones, both represented in the aforementioned code.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested in a more declarative approach, the following did the trick for me. For a given animation, this snippet retrieves the global 3D position of each bone (head and tail) as well as the pixel+depth position with respect to the camera:

```
from bpy_extras.object_utils import world_to_camera_view

armature = ...
cam = ...

pose_bones = {pb.name: pb for pb in D.objects[armature.name].pose.bones}
for frame_i in range(C.scene.frame_start, C.scene.frame_end + 1):
    print("Collecting positions for frame >>>", frame_i)
    # C.scene.frame_current = frame_i
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_i)  # important: refresh scene between frames
    data = {"frame": frame_i}
    for ico_bone, ico in icospheres:
        # get PoseBone global position
        pb_tail = pose_bones[ico_bone].tail
        pb_head = pose_bones[ico_bone].head
        # get PoseBone cam-relative position (0,0)=bottom left, (1,1)=top right
        pb_tail_cam_xyz = world_to_camera_view(C.scene, cam, pb_tail)
        pb_head_cam_xyz = world_to_camera_view(C.scene, cam, pb_head)
```

The approach is based on the following observation:

> At a given frame,the `head` and `tail` fields of the `D.objects[armature.name].pose.bones` show the current global position in `(x, y, z)` coordinates.

I've tested it on `2.90` and seems to work fine, please correct me otherwise! Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Andres

Comment: Minor but the last python code statement uses pb_tail and should use pb_head.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Fixed