# Get bone position without parent's rotation

Tags: python, bones, parent

I'm trying to get the absolute position of a pose bone. To do that, I'm just doing `poseBone.matrix.translation`. That works fine except for a case. If you rotate the bone's parent, the bone's position will change. The system I must use doesn't accept that, so I decided to do this instead:

```
globalPos = poseBone.bone.head_local + poseBone.location * Matrix((poseBone.x_axis, 
                                                                   poseBone.y_axis, 
                                                                   poseBone.z_axis))
```

That works fine but there's one problem with it. When you scale the bone's parent, the bone's position also changes. I need get taht position change in the `globalPos` too, which before woekred fine. But with the no-translation-from-parent-rotation way I don't get the scaling translation. I suppose that, to get it, I must do:

```
globalPos *= poseBone.matrix.to_scale()
```

That, however, doesn't work quite as I expected. So I was wondering, is there any simpler way to do this? (either apply translation from parent's scaling or substracting translation from parent's rotation).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be the same as answer here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/how-to-get-world-space-matrix-of-any-pose-bone

Comment: I'm not having trouble with object transformations, but with bone's parent transforms.

Comment: Is this question restricted to python?  Can you say what your visual goal is?

Comment: "If you rotate the bone's parent, the bone's position will change."
So either use  [matrix_basis](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_1/bpy.types.PoseBone.html?highlight=posebone#bpy.types.PoseBone.matrix_basis) or disable inheritance of rotation, [Bone.use_inherit_rotation](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_1/bpy.types.Bone.html#bpy.types.Bone.use_inherit_rotation), [Bone Relationships](http://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/posing/editing.html?highlight=inherit#effects-of-bones-relationships)

Comment: Thanks, but with `matrix_basis` then translation coming from parent scaling isn't applied there.