# Convert animated bones into empties

Tags: animation, bones, keyframes, conversion

I just created a model (using for a game) that uses several unconnected bones within the same armature to animate the model.

It wasn't until I spent several hours modeling, that I realized the exporter (in this case it is a custom torque .dts exporter) doesn't work with armature/bone animations and only works with objects parented to empties; the empties are then key-frame animated.

Is there a way I can convert/copy all the bones into empties with the same animation movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try exporting the animation as a bvh, then importing back as empties, using the target Object option.

[image]

If that doesn't work could elaborate on https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1287/15543 to create a script to add empties to bone locations.

Comment: This worked great! it wasn't scaled exactly the same but its no biggy.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the empties to the bones. The empties will be animated like the bones and the exporter (hopefully) will export the empties as you want it. That might be quite some work if your model has many bones, but for a simple rig, it'll be fine.