# how to get driver value

Tags: drivers

[image]

how can I get the value of this value as in printable form.

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by 'printable form'?

Answer (score 3):

**Calculate the matrix world of the pose bone.**

An objects matrix world contains its global transform in relation to scene (0, 0, 0) and the global X, Y and Z axes.

See [How to get world-space matrix of any pose bone?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/how-to-get-world-space-matrix-of-any-pose-bone)

This will give the global Y Euler rotation of pose bone TORSO.  The value of the 'VAR' variable in driver in question.

```
import bpy

from math import degrees


ivan = bpy.data.objects["Ivan_rig"]
torso = ivan.pose.bones['TORSO']

# torso global matrix

mw = ivan.matrix_world @ torso.matrix

# angle

angle = mw.to_euler().y

print(f"{angle} ({degrees(angle)})")
print(torso.rotation_axis_angle[:])
```

Output matching driver as shown

[image]

```
-0.3148045539855957 (-18.036972314872912)
```

where the driver variable value is `angle = -0.3148`

Re [your answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/179452/15543), it's demonstrably incorrect. The property is a 4d `(angle, axis.x, axis.y, axis.z)`  Result from example above.

```
(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

default value because my pose bone is not in axis angle rotation mode. Even if it was the angle part would only be global Z rotation when axis is global Z.

Need to convert to global coordinates and convert to Euler to see the WORLD space rotation Y value of driver using this.

Often would use context, eg select the torso bone

```
torso = context.active_pose_bone
```

If using 2.7x or prior replace `@` with `*` to avoid [TypeError: Element-wise multiplication: not supported between 'Matrix' and 'Vector'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129473/typeerror-element-wise-multiplication-not-supported-between-matrix-and-vect)

Comment: Are you serious?

Answer (score 0):

actually figured it out

```
bpy.data.objects['Ivan_rig'].pose.bones['TORSO'].rotation_axis_angle
```